# What is the unit of measurement for scale?

Tags: scale, mapguide

Maybe this is standard across mapping engines, but in MapGuide if I set the scale to 7 million I can see about half the world.  At about 4 million I can see a continent.  What unit of measurement could this scale possibly be in?

Comment: By definition, a scale is *unitless,* because it expresses a ratio of a distance on the map to a distance on the earth.  See [iant's reply](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21392) to your related question and @alex markov's comment below that reply.

Comment: I'm not sure what units means.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134165)

Answer (score 2):

As whuber wrote in his comment: Scale is **unitless**. It expresses a ratio of a distance on the map to a distance on the earth.

e.g. A scale of 1:150,000 means that 1 cm on the map equals 150,000 cm or 1.5 km in the real world.

Answer (score -1):

The convention is 72 pixels to the inch. I couldn't say for sure what MapGuide is using.

Comment: Unless exporting to WMS, 96 pixels/inch is the default for mapguide, and the only possibility when using tiled basemaps.